# Python, Only allow a certain IP address to access get-request

Tags: python, get-request

Im fairly new to python and this may be a stupid question but have been working on a small project that will listen out for a get request and then strip off the useful information and disregard things like (IP of sender or port number). Had my server up for less than a day and noticed a few failed attempts to access it. Is it possible for me to code something along the sorts of:

**E.g. of what my server does:**

```
192.168.1.12:1000/{Server uses info after the slash}
```

Is it possible to make something along the lines of:

```
IP = Requesters IP

if IP != My_IP:
  deny connection
```

Comment: Likely, yes. What modules are you using? If its a raw socket, the `accept` call gives you the connecting address and you can just reset the connection if you don't like it.

Comment: from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

Answer (score 0):

It's been two years now, but I'm putting the answer here for anyone who needs it.
You have to make you own handler, and only give access to the IPs:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHttpHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    allowed_addresses = [
        '192.168.1.50',
    ]

    def __init__(self, *args, directory=None, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, directory=directory, **kwargs)

    def do_GET(self):
        """Serve a GET request."""
        address = self.address_string() # access the IP with this function
        if address in self.allowed_addresses:
            super().do_GET()

HTTPServer(('', 8080), MyHttpHandler).serve_forever()
```

The same goes for `do_POST` if you want to implement it.